# Energy conservation for power nonlinear Schrödinger Equation

Tags: conservation-laws

I'm trying to derive the energy conservation for the one dimensional Schrödinger Equation with power nonlinearity of p=5.

The underlying Lagrange function is given by $$\cal{L}(u(t,x))=\cal{L}(t,x,u,u^*,u_t,u_t^*,u_x,u_x^*)=\frac{i}{2}(uu_t^*-u^*u_t)+|u_x|^2-\frac{1}{3}|u|^6$$ and leads by the Euler-Lagrange equations to the equation of motion $$iu_t+|u|^4u+u_{xx}=0$$
Now using the invariance of the p-NLS and therefore invariance of $\cal{L}(u)$ under time translation $$u(t,x)\mapsto u(t+\epsilon,x)$$ I want to derive the Energy conservation $$E(u(t))=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u_x(t,x)|^2-\frac{1}{6}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u(t,x)|^6=const$$

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Section 2.3 of Sulem-Sulem https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b98958 has this derivation.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that's precisely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:
$$\frac{d}{dt}E(u(t)) = -\operatorname{Re}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \overline{u_t} (\Delta u + u|u|^4)\,dx = -\operatorname{Re}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \overline{u_t} (\Delta u + u|u|^4+iu_t)\,dx =0,$$
where I used integration by part to show that
$$ \partial_t \frac{1}{2}\int |u_x|^2\,dx =\int \operatorname{Re} (u_x \overline{u_{tx}}) \,dx= -\operatorname{Re}\int  \overline{u_t}\Delta u\,dx $$
and
$$\partial_t \frac{1}{6}\int (u\overline{u})^3 = \operatorname{Re} \int (u\overline{u})^2 \overline{u_t}u = \operatorname{Re} \int \overline{u_t} u|u|^4. $$

Comment: Thanks, but my goal isn't to verify the Energy conservation, but to see where it comes from. I know that I need to apply Noether's theorem somehow, but I don't know how to apply it :(